# Verifying formulas

Tags: testing-and-verification

I'm trying to Verify that sin(a + b) = sin(a) cos(b) + sin(b) cos(a) with mathematica, but I don't know how to. I've been given a suggestion to use Simplify, but I don't know where/how.

I just started with Mathematica so forgive me if this has a really simple solution. I've searched around but I haven't found anything.

Comment: TrigExpand[Sin[a + b]]. Also FullSimplify[Cos[b] Sin[a] + Cos[a] Sin[b]]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

There's a nifty little function called `TrigExpand`.

```
Sin[a + b] // TrigExpand
```

> Cos[b] Sin[a] + Cos[a] Sin[b]